# Breaking an if inside a while

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, logic, break

I have the code below.

```
while True:
    if 3 > 2:
        break
```

Will the `break` return back to the `while` and cause an infinite loop, or will it break the `while` and continue in the flow?

Comment: Put some print statements after each line and watch what happens when you run this code.

Comment: Why won't you try it and tell us?

Comment: Another option is to read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement).

Comment: You know that `break` applies to **loops** (`for`/`while`), not `if`, right?

Comment: There's no need to worry about testing things that you think may have an infinite loop: at the command line, you can press Ctrl+C to interrupt the interpreter.

Comment: If you want to do nothing use `pass`

Answer (score 4):

`continue` skips current iteration.
`break` jumps out of the while. Starts executing code just right after it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi it still is - *"Iteration is the act of repeating a process with the aim of approaching a desired goal, target or result."*

Comment: @MalikBrahimi its iterating just not over an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

It will break the loop. Break is a break of the loop, an if else will only fire once if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

break the `while` and continue in the flow

you can test this with some print:

```
while True:
  if 3 > 2:
      print("step1")
      break
  print("step2")

print("step3")
```